load cifar-100 get low test accuracy
when I load cifar-10 with this manner :
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR10
DATA_ROOT = "~/data/cifar-10"

def load_data() -> Tuple[torch.utils.data.DataLoader, torch.utils.data.DataLoader, Dict]:
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]
    )
    trainset = CIFAR10(DATA_ROOT, train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
    testset = CIFAR10(DATA_ROOT, train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
    return trainloader, testloader

I get test_accuracy = 40%, which is good, however when I load cifar 100 with this manner :
from torchvision.datasets import CIFAR100
DATA_ROOT = "~/data/cifar-100"

def load_data() -> Tuple[torch.utils.data.DataLoader, torch.utils.data.DataLoader, Dict]:
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))]
    )
    trainset = CIFAR100(DATA_ROOT, train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
    testset = CIFAR100(DATA_ROOT, train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False)
    return trainloader, testloader

I get test_accuracy = 1% .
I can't understand reasons, knowing that I have same CNN same layers and same def train() and def test()
Help please
